# What do you mean by cross range dimension of a radar's resolution cell?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, radar

I'm reading a book on radars and found this term. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I asked google, and it told me. http://www.radartutorial.eu/20.airborne/ab06.en.html

Comment: I also found the same result but I was unable to understand it. I was looking for a simpler explanation.

Comment: I have translated it into laymans-speak with no maths.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be migrated to http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the radar as a torch.  You hold it in your hand and point it at the floor.  The spot projected by the torch is the "resolution cell".  Point it near your feet and the cell is small, so the cross-range dimension of it is small.  Point it at the floor 20 feet away and the spot is elongated and long.  The cross-range dimension, in that case, is large.  So you get the same resolution (the resolution cell) in a larger space (the cross-range dimension) resulting in lower detail.

Comment: @ja78eXaBEs5u88spebrechawR7mahu just accept his answer as the chosen correct answer. That's the only thanks moderators expect to see around the site (and upvotes when you have rep to do so).